# Turning stocktake data into a dictionary

Tags: python

So I am automating stocktake comparisons, we receive a stock update daily and it needs to be compared to our own stock data to see if there are differences. I think the easiest way of doing this would be to get both stock reports into a dictionary format with {item a, quantity} etc.. I have done this for our own stock but the stock form the warehouse comes in an excel file and it separates each item out by batch number.

I have read this using xlrd using the following:

```
    data = []
    file = file_name
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    row_numbers = range(6, sh.nrows)
    for row in row_numbers:
        if str(sh.row_values(row)[0]).startswith('Sku'):
            data.append(sh.row_values(row)[1:3])
    print(data)
```

and have it in the format of a list of lists. For reference this would look like [item a, 1200], [item a, 4000] etc.. The number of entries per item is not consistent and goes up to 6 but can also be 1. What would be the best method for creating a final dictionary with only one entry per time with a grand total across all of the original lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is iterate through your list of lists, and for each one find whether the item is in the dictionary. If it's not, add it to the dictionary with the quantity as the mapped value. If it already is, look up the mapped value and add the quantity to it.

For example:

```py
final_dict = {}
for entry in list_of_lists:
    final_dict[entry[0]] = final_dict.get(entry[0], 0) + entry[1]
```

Note that here `final_dict.get(x, y)` means look up using the key `x`, and return `y` as a default if x isn't in the dictionary